# I want to split a list of strings to a two dimensional array

Tags: python

I have three sentences in a list:

```
sentences = []
sentence.append("This is my first sentence.")
sentence.append("This is my second sentence.")
sentence.append("This is my third sentence.")
```

I need to split them, so the result should be:
    [['This', 'is', 'my', 'first', 'sentence.'], 
     ['This', 'is', 'my', 'second', 'sentence.'],
     ['This', 'is', 'my', 'third', 'sentence.']]

I tried assign a new list as followed:

```
sentencesplit = []
for i in range(0, 3):
   sentencesplit.extend(sentence[i].split())
```

The result is a one dimensional list containing all the splitted strings in the sentences. I have even tried to declare

```
sentencesplit[[]]
for i in range(0, 3):
   sentencesplit[i].extend(sentence[i].split())
```

but this just result in the error message List index out of range.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can split them while appending itself. `sentences.append("This is my first sentence.".split())`

Comment: why are you using `extend`? There are a lot of useful answers, but if you only changed `extend` into `append` it would work as you asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[sentence.split(' ')  for sentence in sentences]
```

Comment: +1 for the list comprehension simple and readable one-liner. I would have left the `' '`, as it is the standard split, but... Python Zen says it is ok to be explicit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "append":

```
sentencesplit = []
for i in range(0, 3):
   sentencesplit.append(sentence[i].split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentenceList = ["This is my first sentence.",
                "This is my second sentence.",
                "This is my third sentence."]
result = []
for i in range(len(sentenceList)):
    result.append(sentenceList[i].split(" "))
```

**print result**

```
[['This', 'is', 'my', 'first', 'sentence.'], 
 ['This', 'is', 'my', 'second', 'sentence.'], 
 ['This', 'is', 'my', 'third', 'sentence.']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple `map` and `lambda` to make the list:

```
>>> strs = ['This is an example','This is an example','This is an example']
>>> map(lambda split_str: split_str.split(' '), strs)
[['This', 'is', 'an', 'example'], ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example'], ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']]
```

Or without `lamdba`:

```
>>> import string
>>> strs = ['This is an example','This is an example','This is an example']
>>> map(string.split, strs)
[['This', 'is', 'an', 'example'], ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example'], ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']]
```

Comment: Hah, beat me to it. I was about to create that shorter version. +1 >> Edit: Looks like we have a serial downvoter...

Answer (score 0):

```
sentences = []
sentences.append("This is my first sentence.".split())
sentences.append("This is my second sentence.".split())
sentences.append("This is my third sentence.".split())
```

Split them before appending.